# How to get the post-ID in my plugin?

Tags: themes, post-meta

I am trying to write a little plugin which allows me to add a different theme to each page. well.. still trying.. ;)

code: http://pastebin.com/dP1GH43E

When I put `return 'mytesttheme';` at the end it works just perfect!
when I add an ID (`$page_theme = get_post_meta('66', [...]`) it also works..

when I write `echo $page_theme.', ';` before the return, it outputs: `, , , mytesttheme, mytesttheme, mytesttheme, mytesttheme,`

The empty spaces are the problem I think.

in wp-backend it shows "mytesttheme" as post meta content in wp-core post meta content box.. so the saving works as it should..

Any ideas how to solve the problem? :S

Comment: this:
`global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;

if ($postid == '') :
 echo 'NO-ID, ';
else :
 echo get_post_meta($postid, 'page_theme', true) .', ';
endif;`

returns:
**NO-ID, NO-ID, NO-ID, NO-ID, NO-ID, NO-ID, NO-ID, cuttlefish, cuttlefish,**

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code. Let's start at the beginning...

**Adding hooks**

**All** your hooks will be added at the backend. Even those which are outside the `if((is_admin))` branch. Add your hooks explicitly where they should work:

```
if (is_admin()){
  // do this on backend (admin side)
    /* load plugin functions */
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box');
    add_action('save_post', 'myplugin_save_meta_box');

} else {
  // if we are NOT on backend (admin side) we have to be on frontend, because there is only frontend and backend.
    /* load page theme */
    add_filter( 'option_template', 'my_plugin_get_page_theme');
    add_filter( 'template', 'my_plugin_get_page_theme');
    add_filter( 'option_stylesheet', 'my_plugin_get_page_theme');

}
```

**In the loop or not?**

`get_the_ID()` must be within the loop. Where are your hooks ('option_template', 'template' and 'option_stylesheet') are done? Before the query is done or after (means: inside the loop or outside) ?
Two lines of code give us the answer:

```
global $post;
var_dump( $post );
```

If `$post` is empty (null), we are outside the loop. We hooked to early. We need a hook after the query is done. The ´init´ hook is an odd one. Let's alter the code above a bit and get the plugin working:

```
if (is_admin()){

    /* load plugin functions */
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box');
    add_action('save_post', 'myplugin_save_meta_box');

} else {

    add_action( 'init', 'my_template_hooks', 5, 0 );

}

    function my_template_hooks(){

        /* load page theme */
        add_filter( 'option_template', 'my_plugin_get_page_theme');
        add_filter( 'template', 'my_plugin_get_page_theme');
        add_filter( 'option_stylesheet', 'my_plugin_get_page_theme');

    }
```

Now our hooks are inside the loop and the plugin works fine.

**Deprecated function**

On line 28 of your plugin code you use `$themes = get_themes();`. `get_themes()` is deprecated and should be replaced with ´wp_get_themes()´.

**Development**

Please enable WP-debugging (set WP_DEBUG to TRUE in your wp-config.php). The debug messages will help you much.

You can find the complete modified code on [Github](https://gist.github.com/4145401)

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, to use **post->ID** outside of loop, **wp_query** should be called first. I mean something like that the code bellow which is already suggested by @Jan

```
global $wp_query; 
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
```

Optionally, `get_post_id()` can work for you, check [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) for more.

Comment: thank 4 thinking about it, but "Jan" is just me ;)
when i do it that way the id is not always transfered.. :S

Comment: Ops, I missed the name of querist. Anyway, did you try `get_the_ID()`?